# Is there a way to make a .bat file that wrench exclusive control over sound and free it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, audio, windows-8, device-driver

If not, is there a way to find what device keeps on doing it? I have turned the setting off. Disabling then re-enabling the audio driver does not work, but disabling it then restarting and turning it back on works, until whatever it is steals it again. Just tell me if this is the wrong section, then tell me which would be more appropriate. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not understanding the use of the word 'wrench' in your title.

Comment: Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device is a setting. Can you make a batch file that takes exclusive control then ends so other applications can use sound?